# Handling Multi Value Parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm having `6 filters` on my SSRS, out of which `1 is of Department`. I have to select `multiple departments` and on the basis of these selections, Report will be generated. But I'm not getting how to make this done.

I created a `stored procedure` which is getting called in Reports.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_getLessonLearntDetails]
@AssetID nvarchar(50),
@DepartmentID nvarchar(50),
@Category varchar(50),
@AuditType varchar(50),
@AuditStartYear nvarchar(50),
@AuditEndYear nvarchar(50)

AS

BEGIN

SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AssetName ASC) AS Sno,
LLD.LessonComputedID, tbl_Asset.AssetName, AT.AuditType, SY.Year+' - '+EY.Year as 'Audit Period',
DE.DepartmentName, CT.CategoryName, LLD.Learnings, 
CAST(CASE WHEN (LLD.RepeatedObservation = 1) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS varchar(10)) as RepeatedObservation, 
LLD.RepeatedObservationReference, Att.Attachment
FROM         tbl_LessonLearntDetails LLD INNER JOIN
             tbl_Category CT ON CT.CategoryID = LLD.Title  INNER JOIN
             tbl_Asset ON LLD.AssetID = tbl_Asset.AssetID INNER JOIN
             tbl_Department DE ON LLD.DepartmentID = DE.DepartmentID INNER JOIN
             tbl_AuditType AT ON LLD.AuditTypeID = AT.AuditTypeID INNER JOIN
             tbl_Attachment Att ON LLD.LessonLearntID= Att.LeassonLearntID INNER JOIN
             tbl_AuditYear SY on SY.Year = LLD.AuditStartYear INNER JOIN                   
             tbl_AuditYear EY on EY.Year = LLD.AuditEndYear

        where ( (('0'=@AssetID and (1=1)) or LLD.AssetID=@AssetID) and 
                (('0'=@DepartmentID and (1=1)) or LLD.DepartmentID IN (@DepartmentID)) and
                (('0'=@Category and (1=1)) or LLD.Title=@Category) and
                (('0'=@AuditType and (1=1)) or LLD.AuditTypeID=@AuditType) and
                (('0'=@AuditStartYear and (1=1)) or (LLD.AuditStartYear >= @AuditStartYear)) and
                (('0'=@AuditEndYear and (1=1)) or (LLD.AuditEndYear <= @AuditEndYear))
              );

END;
```

Comment: You can either use a table valued parameter or pass in a comma seperated list and use `LIKE` to check against that

Comment: @MWillemse SSRS does not know what table valued parameter is ad does not pass nothing to the sp

Comment: @Aakash Srivastava you should pass your multi-valued parameter as varchar(...) and SSRS will pass in a comma-separated list. Then you should use splitting function

Comment: if you can... Don't use a stored proc. Just copy the main code section of your SP into the dataset query and that's it. @Department will be passed in and injected into your SQL statement as comma separated values. There is no need to do anything else, no splitting, joining etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Split Function will work here. I did it.

In where condition, use split function.

```
(('0'=@DepartmentID AND (1=1)) OR LLD.DepartmentID IN (SELECT * FROM fnSplit(@DepartmentID,',')))
```

Thanks everyone for your response. Because of you guys only I will be able to get hit by an idea of Splitting.